# How to use GWT JsArray to create nested arrays

Tags: gwt

How to create nested arrays using gwt JsArray.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same way you create a nested Collection in Java, you can create a nested JsArray:

```
    JsArray<JsArray<JavaScriptObject>> myArray = JavaScriptObject.createArray().cast();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        JsArray<JavaScriptObject> innerArray = JavaScriptObject.createArray().cast();
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            innerArray.push(JavaScriptObject.createObject());
        }
        myArray.push(innerArray);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks You very much I was looking for this for a long time